# TextChanged firing multiple time on MaskEditing

Tags: c#, wpf

I've already checked similar questions, but i couldn't find any working answer my own code

I wanted to write a code to text mask-editing
But when im debugging the code, it fired multiple times on each time i write text inside of textbox

It does correct work on first time, but it's like in a for-loop and does method many times.

Help me!

```
   public class Resp
    {
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public int Caret { get; set; }
    }

    public static Resp Masker(this string text, string mask, int caretIndex, bool ShowPlaceHolder)
    {
        string result;
        if (text.Length <= mask.Length || caretIndex > 0)
        {
            var workingArray = new List<int>();
            var maskArray = mask.ToArray();
            for (var i = 0; i < mask.Length; i++)
                if (maskArray[i] == '_')
                    workingArray.Add(i);

            var textArray = text.ToArray();
            var resultArray = new List<char>();

            var indicator = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < maskArray.Length; i++)
            {
                var current = maskArray[i];

                var writableIndex = workingArray.IndexOf(i);
                if (writableIndex == -1 || indicator == text.Length)
                {
                    resultArray.Add(current);
                    continue;
                }

                resultArray.Add(textArray[indicator]);
                indicator++;
            }

            result = string.Concat(resultArray);
        }
        else
        {
            result = text;
        }

        return new Resp
        {
            Text = result,
            Caret = caretIndex
        };
    }

    private void TxtMobile_OnTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!(sender is TextBox textBox)) return;

        var process = textBox.Text.Masker("09__ ___ ____", textBox.CaretIndex, true);
        textBox.Text = process.Text;
        textBox.CaretIndex = process.Caret;
    }
```

Comment: TextChanged events fire after every character, isnt that your issue?

Comment: @iSpain17 no, when i enter a character, it does `Masker` method correctly, for the first time. but after that, it changes input `text` to `mask`

Comment: `if (!(sender is TextBox textBox)) return;` this cannot be compiled

Comment: @kennyzx no, nothing changed in result after do you suggestion. i think problem is around `for-lopp` in `Masker` method

Comment: @ArashSh I am just saying that this line is syntactically wrong, it should be `if (!(sender is TextBox)) return;`, right?

Comment: @kennyzx you're wrong, the code is correct and i'm using it now. my major problem is in `Masker` method, right?

Comment: I didn't know this, maybe it is a new syntax to me. please check my answer for your major problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is sure to be fired multiple times, because you are changing the Text of the `TextBlock` in its `TextChanged` event handler, which results in recursive calls - by changing the Text you are firing another `TextChanged` event.

An old trick to workaround this is temporarily un-register the event handler before changing the Text, and re-register the handler after the change is made. Like this

```
var process = textBox.Text.Masker("09__ ___ ____", textBox.CaretIndex, true);
textBox.TextChanged -= TxtMobile_OnTextChanged; //unregister 
textBox.Text = process.Text;
textBox.TextChanged += TxtMobile_OnTextChanged; //re-register
textBox.CaretIndex = process.Caret;
```

Comment: yo yo yo it worked thank you. by the way, i think that syntax i for `C# 7+`